# WPF TreeView Scrolled to Bottom automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

WPF default TreeView is scrolled to bottom of the node automatically where as we need to show the top view of the tree view. How to do that?

Also I could not get the scroll viewer by walking down the Visual Tree.

Answer (score 1):

Preselect top node and call TreeViewItem.BringIntoView method on selection changed event. Call TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.NewValue) to get hold of the TreeViewItem.

Answer (score 1):

This code is very rough.
The key to getting the TreeViewItem.BringIntoView() to get an item to the top, is to first scroll the TreeView to the bottom rather than the top.
To do this, we need to access the ScrollViewer inside the TreeView's control template first.  Lots of messing around IMO, that should have been provided in the framework from the outset.

Your item control in this case, should be your TreeViewItem that you are trying to get to the top.
The uxTree control is the TreeView.

```
item.IsSelected = true;
ScrollViewer scroller = (ScrollViewer)this.FindVisualChildElement(this.uxTree, typeof(ScrollViewer));
scroller.ScrollToBottom();
item.BringIntoView();

private FrameworkElement FindVisualChildElement(DependencyObject element, Type childType)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
        var fe = (FrameworkElement)dependencyObject;

        if (fe.GetType() == childType)
        {
            return fe;
        }

        FrameworkElement ret = null;

        if (fe.GetType().Equals(typeof(ScrollViewer)))
        {
            ret = FindVisualChildElement((fe as ScrollViewer).Content as FrameworkElement, childType);
        }
        else
        {
            ret = FindVisualChildElement(fe, childType);
        }

        if (ret != null)
        {
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```